# Xcode 14 Xcode 13 incompatibility

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode13, xcode14

When I manually add the SDK that I exported in Xcode 13 to xcode 13 and xcode 14, it works for all devices without any problems. But when I export in xcode 14, it only works for simulators in xcode 13, I can't build on real devices, (in xcode 14 it works on all devices without any problems). For the SDK I exported in Xcode 14, the errors I get when I run it on real device in xcode 13 are as follows:

```
directory not found for option '-F/(framework path)'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:_objc_msgSend$subfiles
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:_objc_msgSend$subfiles
...
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I deleted the framework search path for the directory not found error and I found a solution to it, but I couldn't find a solution for the errors I got for all the sub-files of the SDK below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:_objc_msgSend$subfiles
```

And

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your comments.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? What SDK, which Mac, which macOS ?

Comment: @PtitXav Hello. Actually, it's a framework I created myself. I am using m1 macbook. Version macOS 12.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long research, I discovered the solution. Clang emits objc_msgSend in Xcode 14; previous versions of Xcode don't understand it. This needs to be disabled. Here is the [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16223) I used for the solution. Commited changes are available at this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/commit/dec29fe4339e1a2ca5df11fdd969130a4c1dc443). Big thanks to these guys.

By the way, selecting the compatible version for Xcode 14 of **Command Line Tools** from **XCode > Preferences > Locations** section, and also updating the **Clang version (you can type clang -v in the terminal)** to be compatible with this version.
You can add `-fno-objc-msgsend-selector-stubs` settings to **C Flags under Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags from Targets > Build Setting** directly from Xcode

Comment: Thanks for this solution @batuhan - I'm not completely adept at using XCode. I've tried pasting that `-fno-objc-msgsend-selector-stubs` line in under C Flags and I keep getting errors. Are you able to give any further details on how to add this flag in XCode? Thanks!